# PHPUnit xdebug.coverage_enable=On message

Tags: macos, phpunit, xdebug

How to get through "You need to set xdebug.coverage_enable=On in your php.ini." message?
I have set xdebug.coverage_enable=On in the proper (--ini) php.ini file but it had no effect. Im on mac os x snow leopard

Answer (score 1):

What version of xdebug are you using?

```
php --ri xdebug
```

will tell you that version (amongst everything else)

PHP_CodeCoverage 1.0.2 (which is used by PHPUnit to collect code coverage information) has this bit of source code

```
if (version_compare(phpversion('xdebug'), '2.2.0-dev', '>=') &&
    !ini_get('xdebug.coverage_enable')) {
    die("You need to set xdebug.coverage_enable=On in your php.ini.\n");
}
```

Based on this logic you would get this error only if you have installed xdebug 2.2.0-dev. Which, in my opinion should not be used before it is stable.

xdebug 2.1.0 is stable and works well enough.

If you however are not running 2.2.0-dev, then this starts to look like a bug, and you need to give more information about what versions of everything relevant you are using.

**Update** - it looks like this was an actual [bug in PHP_CodeCoverage that was fixed in 1.0.2](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/blob/1.0/PHP/CodeCoverage/Driver/Xdebug.php) 3 days ago. You probably had an older version. Upgrade, and it should be fine now.

Comment: strangely I don't see xdebug on my php info page, but typing php -i | grep xdebug gives all info normally

Comment: Can I just delete those lines from PHP_CodeCoverage? Where would I find this package on macos?

Comment: What Im trying to do actually is to run PHPUnit like so-
Covax:tests toyota8$ phpunit functional/SiteTest.php and get the message:
You need to set xdebug.coverage_enable=On in your php.ini.

Comment: Also, NetBeans is not connecting to xdebug even tho I have the following in php.ini:xdebug.remote_enable = on
;xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"

Comment: Im using zend_extension=/full/path/to/xdebug.so in php.ini

Comment: You will the code with the above check in your Pear directory - 'pear config-get php_dir' in the file PHP/CodeCoverage/Driver/Xdebug.php

Comment: @toyota: Maybe you are using different PHP components which don't have all libraries linked across them. E.g.: in Ubuntu, you can separately install PHP-CGI, PHP-CLI and PHP-FPM. Some PHP extensions, when installed, just drop an .ini file in mods-enabled folder and don't link that file to actual components - you have to do that manually (Xdebug does that in Ubuntu, so does php-mongo). So maybe you have Xdebug enabled in PHP-CLI, but not in PHP-FPM etc. PHP configuration needs to be checked for all its components and you need to make sure all components share same settings.